# Request to switch which question is a duplicate of the other

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

The two questions are:

- [Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-a-remote-repository-uri-using-git)
- [How can I change the remote/target repository URL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800859/how-can-i-change-the-remote-target-repository-url-on-windows)

The first is currently closed as a duplicate of the second one, which is technically correct as it was posted later.  However, there's several reasons it was a bad choice:

- The question itself is cross-platform.

  - As is the accepted answer, which was posted in both questions.
- Far more massive upvotes in both question and answers, indicating it is better/more helpful.
- Google is sending users to the closed one due to its better searchability (above even `help.github.com`!).  The open one doesn't even appear in the search results.

Comment: My Google search was `git change remote path`, for the curious